# RestSharp API POST - identical data different return status

Tags: c#, rest, .net-core, restsharp

I have Test Data defined as follows:

```
public static string body = @"#--------1---------2---------3---------4---------5-------
#PlanetName   Loc. UPP Code   B   Notes         Z  PBG Al
#----------   ---- ---------  - --------------- -  --- --
Cogrikonur    0101 C8C5446-9    Fl Ni              120 Im";
```

I have the following method:

```
 public byte[] CreateSectorMapNoMeta(string data, string subsector)
    {
        byte[] result;

        var request = new RestRequest($"https://travellermap.com/api/poster?subsector={subsector}", Method.Post);
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");
        request.AddHeader("Accept", "image/svg+xml");
        
        request.AddParameter("text/plain", data, ParameterType.RequestBody);

        RestResponse response = _rest.Execute(request);

        if (response.IsSuccessful)
        {
            result = response.RawBytes;
        }
        else
        {
            result = null;
        }

        return result;
    }
```

The parameters are data = the test data above, subsector = "A"  It is called like this:

```
MapData.CreateSectorMapNoMeta(TestData.body, "A");
```

When I try to execute this method it fails with a Code 400 Bad Request.

However the following method works,

```
  public byte[] CreateSectorMapTest()
    {
         byte[] result;

        var client = new RestClient("https://travellermap.com/api/poster?subsector=A");

        var request = new RestRequest("https://travellermap.com/api/poster?subsector=A", Method.Post);
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");
        request.AddHeader("Accept", "image/svg+xml");

        var body = @"#--------1---------2---------3---------4---------5-------
#PlanetName   Loc. UPP Code   B   Notes         Z  PBG Al
#----------   ---- ---------  - --------------- -  --- --
Cogrikonur    0101 C8C5446-9    Fl Ni              120 Im";
        
        request.AddParameter("text/plain", body, ParameterType.RequestBody);
        RestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

        if (response.IsSuccessful)
        {
            result = response.RawBytes;
        }
        else
        {
            result = null;
        }

        return result;
    }
```

As can be plainly seen the data in the second call is the same as in the first method, however in the second method the post succeeds, while the first raises a Bad Request exception.  Can someone help me to understand what I am doing wrong.

Update: I solved this by playing with the RestSharp client constructor.  I had followed the Getting Started guide, and tried to use a pre-configured http client as per Using Your own HttpClient.  Because the only difference between the two code blocks was the way the RestClient was instantiated I decided the problem must be there.

When I added the same constructor to the failing method and used it, it worked, so i changed the constructor for the object and it now works.

Original Unworking Code:

```
 private HttpClient _http;
    private RestClient _rest;

    //the base URL for Traveller Map API endpoints
    private string baseUrl = @"https://travellermap.com/api/";
    
    public TravellerClient()
    {
        _http = new HttpClient();
        _http.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUrl);
        _rest = new RestClient(_http);
    }
```

New Code That Works:

```
 private HttpClient _http;
    private RestClient _rest;

    //the base URL for Traveller Map API endpoints
    private string baseUrl = @"https://travellermap.com/api/";
    
    public TravellerClient()
    {
        _http = new HttpClient();
        _http.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUrl);
        _rest = new RestClient(baseUrl);
    }
```

As can be seen when using the Http client in the constructor for the RestSharp client the base URL seems to be ignored, and it has to be explicitly set.  Is this an issue that should be reported?  Does anyone know of a way this can work with reusing the httpclient in the RestSharp client constructor?

Comment: Did the post request return any error message?

Comment: Full error is:  StatusCode: BadRequest, Content-Type: text/plain, Content-Length: 55), Exception: System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Request failed with status code BadRequest, Error Message: Null